# How to build and run the GNU GAS assembler test suite?

Tags: assembly, gas, binutils

I'm at Binutils tag `binutils-2_31`, and there is a directory:

```
gas/testsuite
```

with some tests that I'm interested in.

I've compiled the entire binutils with:

```
./configure
make
```

but the directory `gas/testsuite` didn't seem to be built.

How to build and run those tests?

Hopefully in verbose mode so I can see the full GAS command line.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to run the tests with:

```
sudo apt-get install dejagnu
cd gas
make check
```

This runs the tests just for the target architecture you configured for of course. For example, for aarch64 tests:

```
./configure --target aarch64-elf
cd gas
make check
```

runs only the tests under:

```
gas/testsuite/gas/aarch64
```

You can confirm this by hacking one of the tests to fail. E.g., try editing:

```
gas/testsuite/gas/aarch64/addsub.s
```

to something wrong and watch it report a failure.

The generated log files seem to contain more information about what was run exactly:

```
gas/testsuite/gas.log
gas/testsuite/gas.sum
```

Found with my loyal friends `git clean -xdn` and `ls -lSr`.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.